# How can I replace a nested list of phrases with dashes?

Tags: python, list, nested

If I have

```
LIST=[['SPORTS','NEW YORK JETS']]
```

and I want to replace the second element of my sublist (`NEW YORK JETS`) to `___ ____ ____`, how can I do that?

So far, I have:

```
hide = ""
for l in LIST:
 if l[1] != " ":
  hide = hide + "_"
else:
  hide = hide + " "
print(hide)
```

This doesn't give me the desired output. I'd appreciate any suggestions.

Thank You!

Comment: Be careful, naming a variable `list` is a bad idea.

Comment: @AMC `LIST != list`

Comment: @Barmar Yes, but `LIST` has no reason to be all caps, it would be changed to `list`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to loop over the characters in the string in a nested loop, and replace the non-space characters with `_`.

```
result = []
for word1, word2 in LIST:
    hide = ""
    for c in word2:
        if c == " ":
            hide += " "
        else:
            hide += "_"
    result.append([word1, hide])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can build a new list using list comprehension and calculating the length of each word replacing them with `_` like this:

```py
values = [['SPORTS','NEW YORK JETS'], ['SPORTS2','NEW YORK JETS2']]
hidden = [
    [ 
        v[0], 
        ' '.join('_'*len(word) for word in  v[1].split())
    ] for v in values
]

print(hidden)

>>> [['SPORTS', '___ ____ ____'], ['SPORTS2', '___ ____ _____']]
```

Comment: I assume he wants the number of underscores to match the number of alphanumeric characters in the original string, so you can't use a fixed string in your replacement.

Comment: Oh, didn't think about that, let me update the answer then! Thanks! @Barmar

Comment: So, each sublist is bigger than 2 elements? @RicAlex

Comment: What makes you ask that? Morgan Leclerc seems to have made that assumption in his answer, but there's nothing like it in the question.

Comment: @Barmar he added a comment (currently deleted) saying that this didn't work for him, so one possible explanation is that one.

Answer (score 0):

try with this

```
LIST=[['SPORTS','NEW YORK JETS']]
hide = []
for l in LIST:
 sub = []
 for sub_l in l : 
   s = ""
   for c in sub_l : 
     if c != " " :
      s += "_"
     else :
      s += " "
   sub.append(s)
hide.append(sub)

print(hide)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use built-in function enumerate and filter list elements based on index:

```py
lizt = [
    ['sports', 'new york jets', 'even more values if you want'],
    ['sports2', 'new york jets2', 'even more values if you want2'],
    # ...
]

hide_list = []
for nested_list in lizt:
    hide_nested_list = []
    for index, value in enumerate(nested_list):
        if index == 1:
            hide_nested_list.append('___ ____ ____')
        else:
            hide_nested_list.append(value)
    hide_list.append(hide_nested_list)

print(hide_list)
```

It is way shorter with list comprehensions:

```py
lizt = [
    ['sports', 'new york jets', 'even more values if you want'],
    ['sports2', 'new york jets2', 'even more values if you want2'],
    # ...
]

hide_list = [
    [v for i, v in enumerate(l) if i != 1 else '___ ____ ____'] for l in lizt
]

print(hide_list)
```

Comment: They only need to replace the 2nd element of the nested list. There's no suggestion that it can be longer than 2 or that the additional elements need to be replaced.

Comment: And I think the number of underscores should match the length of the words, not be hard-coded like this.